# Serving multiple socket using gunicorn and Nginx cause a NotFound error

Tags: nginx, socket, gunicorn, flask

I am trying to serve two Flask apps using Nginx as a reverse proxy. In my `default.conf`  which I have reloaded using `sudo service nginx restart` I have got:

```
    location /app2loc/ {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/app2/app.sock;
    }
    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/app1/app.sock;
    }
```

The first app `app1` is running without any problem when I access it at `www.mydomain.com`. The second app `app2` seems running with any error as proof, this is the output of `sudo systemctl status app2.service`:

```
● app2.service - Gunicorn instance to serve Flask app2.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/capitcatalog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-04-01 18:11:28 CEST; 26min ago
 Main PID: 24762 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 25 (limit: 4423)
   CGroup: /system.slice/capitcatalog.service
           ├─24762 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/gunicorn --chdir /var/www/html/app2/ -w 3 -b unix:app.sock -m 007 
           ├─24778 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/gunicorn --chdir /var/www/html/app2/ -w 3 -b unix:app.sock -m 007 
           ├─24779 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/gunicorn --chdir /var/www/html/app2/ -w 3 -b unix:app.sock -m 007 
           └─24780 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/app2/env/bin/gunicorn --chdir /var/www/html/app2/ -w 3 -b unix:app.sock -m 007
```

However, when I try to access it using `www.mydomain.com/app2loc` I have a

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

**I was wondering what could be the mistake. Why the second socket seems not accessible?**

This is the output of `nginx -T`:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # ADDED FOR UV VIEWR
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$host$uri";


}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

server {
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/;

    # this is working properly 
    location /vrt/ {
            alias /var/www/html/vrt/; 
        }

    location /app2/ {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/app2/app.sock;
        }

}        

# configuration file /etc/nginx/proxy_params:
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is accessible, and the "Not found" error is returned by the app server on that socket.

Most likely this happens because nginx will forward a request to `/app2loc` to your second application server.

Change the `proxy_pass` for app2 to:

```
location /app2loc/ {
    proxy_pass http://app2/;
}

upstream app2 {
    server unix:/var/www/html/app2/app.sock;
}
```

The extra `/` at end of `proxy_pass` makes nginx strip the `app2loc` prefix from the URI passed to upstream.

Remember also to configure your application's base URL to include the `app2loc` prefix.